# Python - Boolean tested while loop is never ending

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Hi I am trying to program a raspberry pi Sense hat that moves a pixel around the Matrix using the accelorometer. The idea is to get to the red area to win. If however it hits the green yellow or blue the game will end in a loss. When it finds one of the colours it is suppose to change the boolean varialb e(game_over) to True thus breaking the loop to stop the game.

The problem is when it reads that a colour was hit it changes the variable game_over to True, but then it some how changes back to False when it returns to the while loop. I have tested this using print statements to see what happens.

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import sleep

sense = SenseHat()
sense.clear()

r = [150,0,0]
g = [0,150,0]
j = [150,150,0]
b = [0,0,150]
e = [0,0,0]
w = [255,255,255]
v = [125,150,175]

x = 4
y = 4

maze = [[r,r,r,r,r,r,r,b],
        [g,r,r,r,r,r,b,b],
        [g,g,e,e,e,e,b,b],
        [g,g,e,e,e,e,b,b],
        [g,g,e,e,e,e,b,b],
        [g,g,e,e,e,e,b,b],
        [g,g,j,j,j,j,j,b],
        [g,j,j,j,j,j,j,j]]

false = [
    r,e,e,e,e,e,e,r,
    e,r,e,e,e,e,r,e,
    e,e,r,e,e,r,e,e,
    e,e,e,r,r,e,e,e,
    e,e,e,r,r,e,e,e,
    e,e,r,e,e,r,e,e,
    e,r,e,e,e,e,r,e,
    r,e,e,e,e,e,e,r]


def move_marble(pitch,roll,x,y):
    new_x = x
    new_y = y
    if 1 < pitch < 179 and x != 0:
        new_x -= 1
    elif 359 > pitch > 179 and x != 7 :
        new_x += 1
    if 1 < roll < 179 and y != 7:
        new_y += 1
    elif 359 > roll > 179 and y != 0 :
        new_y -= 1
    x,y = check_wall(x,y,new_x,new_y)
    return x,y

def check_wall(x,y,new_x,new_y):
    if maze[new_y][new_x] != v:
        return new_x, new_y
    elif maze[new_y][x] != v:
        return x, new_y
    elif maze[y][new_x] != v:
        return new_x, y
    return x,y

game_over = False

def check_win(x,y):
    sleep(0.25)
    if maze[y][x] == r:
        sense.show_message('Vous avez gagner', scroll_speed=0.08)
        sleep(1)
        game_over = True
    elif maze[y][x] == j: 
        sense.set_pixels(false)
        game_over = True
        sleep(1)
        sense.show_message('Vous avez perdu', scroll_speed=0.08)

    elif maze[y][x] == b:
        sense.set_pixels(false)
        game_over = True
        sleep(1)
        sense.show_message('Vous avez perdu', scroll_speed=0.08)

    elif maze[y][x] == g:
        sense.set_pixels(false)
        game_over = True
        sleep(1)
        sense.show_message('Vous avez perdu', scroll_speed=0.08)


while game_over == False:
    pitch = sense.get_orientation()['pitch']
    roll = sense.get_orientation()['roll']
    x,y = move_marble(pitch,roll,x,y)
    check_win(x,y)
    maze[y][x] = w
    sense.set_pixels(sum(maze,[]))
    sleep(0.1)
    maze[y][x] = e
sense.clear()
```

I'm sure it is something small, I just can not seem to find it.